# Route to specific server over a single IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, local-area-network, wide-area-network

Is there any way to route a request from a specific subdomain to a specific server over a single external IP address. 
So for example Sub1.Domain.com:1234 goes to 12.34.45.6 and enters my local network then it should route to 192.168.1.26:1234 on my local network.
Like in this scheme in included:
[image: Scheme]

Comment: The proper solution is to allocate a separate IP address to each server. Everything else is just workarounds. Workarounds exist for HTTP, HTTPS, SMTP, and DNS. I am aware of no other protocol for which a workaround is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The firewall/NAT box may be able to do it and it will only take you several hours to come up with the rule-syntax to achieve it...

It may be more straightforward, if these "special" clients accessed a dedicated *port* -- then the syntax will be easier to figure out.

But @kasperd is right -- it is all a work-around...